# Qualitative behavior of critical point at the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the qualitative behavior of the critical point at the origin for the following system for **all** possible values of $a$:

$\dot{x} = -y + ax(x^2+y^2)$

$\dot{y} = x + ay(x^2+y^2)$

**My question:** I attempted to use the Local Center Manifold theorem to show that the center manifold: $x = h(y) = a_0 + a_1y+a_2y^2 +...$ for $a_0, a_1, ...$ are parameters to be determined and $h(0) = h'(0) = 0$, must be $0$. To do this, assume $h(y)\neq 0$ for $y\neq 0$. Now, we replace $x$ by $h(y)$ from the sysem above, and from the identity: $\dot{x} = \dot{y}\  h'(y)$, we get the following equation for all values of $a$:

$-y + a(a_0 + a_1y+ a_2y^2 + ...) (a_0^2+a_1^2y^2 + 2a_0a_1y+2a_0a_2y^2 +...+y^2) = (a_1 + 2a_2y + 3a_3y^2 + ...)[a_0 + a_1y+ a_2y^2 + ... + ay(a_0^2 + a_1^2y^2 + 2a_0a_1y + 2a_0a_2y^2 + ... +y^2)]$

Since $h(0) = h'(0) = 0$, we instantly get $a_0 = a_1 = 0$. But then the $-y$ term on the LHS of the equation above is never cancelled with anything, so the equation, after matching terms by terms, cannot be true for every $y\neq 0$. Thus $h(y)$ does not exist in this case.

Therefore, $h(y) = 0$ is the only choice, which implies $x = 0$. But if this is the case, then $0 = -y$, so $y = 0$ as well. Thus the critical point is a saddle point? Is this a correct conclusion?

Comment: This vector field is a perfect candidate for Lyapunov stability. Are you familiar at all with Lyapunov functions and Lyapunov's second method for stability?

Comment: @GaussTheBauss: Thank you for your insight! I'm familiar with it, but it's quite hard to find explicitly a Lyapunov function. How do you decide to approach it by using Lyapunov function? Can you point out for me what went wrong with my method above?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with your method. I did however elaborate a little bit on the Lyapunov method below. Find the correct function comes from practice. The example you have posted is a classic problem. When you vector field is polynomial (and symmetric in your case!), then the Lyapunov function will also be a polynomial, and will be symmetric.

Comment: Ehrm. We have two dimensional system and critical point with purely imaginary eigenvalues. We have two non-hyperbolic eigenvalues out of two possible eigenvalues. There is _no way_ to find one-dimensional center manifold in this case. So that's the reason why everything fails -- center manifold is two dimensional here.

Comment: To provide some context you could mention that the system does not satisfy the hypothesis of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman-Grobman_theorem

Comment: @Evgeny: thank you for your explaination. But as someone pointed out, since the H-G failed in this case, how can you check for the eigenvalues of $0$? I meant, we can't really have equivalence between this sytem and the linearized one in this case, so we don't know how to find eigenvalues. If a center manifold exists, what is its form? A follow-up question is: which invariant manifold exists at the origin?

Comment: Fail of G-H just means that your non-linear system is not equivalent to its linearization. It means that Jacobi matrix is non-hyperbolic (i.e., there are eigenvalues on imaginary axis). Situation becomes more subtle: in this case there is a statement that there exists a center manifold that is tangent to eigenspace spanned by eigenvectors with zero real part. In your case the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ corresponds to this eigenspace.

Comment: how can we determine the eigenspace of a nonhyperbolic equilibrium, if we don't have the equivalence of nonlinear to linear? How can you find the two-dimensional center manifold in this case?

Comment: First, you are constantly forgetting to mention people whom you are asking in comments. Second, I've told nothing about equivalence of nonlinear to linear and finding eigenspaces of Jacobi matrix doesn't require that. Third, as I've already said, you have *two-dimensional* system with *two-dimensional* center eigenspace. In this case your local center manifold is just any disk around origin. Because center manifold is tangent to center eigenspace and has the same dimension as the eigenspace.

Comment: @Evgeny: I'm sorry for forgetting to tag you, sinceI thought my last question is directly geared towards you? Anyway, great answer. I'm so dumb not to realize that it's a disk:((

Comment: No, you have to mention people explicitly if you want them to be notified. Just don't forget that dimensions of stable/unstable/center manifolds always coincides with dimension of respective subspace of Jacobi matrix :)

Comment: Why not to write this system in polar coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not the method you were going for, but I could not resist offering another possible solution.

According to the Wikipedia article on [Lyapunov Stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability):

> Lyapunov, in his original 1892 work, proposed two methods for
>   demonstrating stability. The first method developed the solution in
>   a series which was then proved convergent within limits. The second
>   method, which is almost universally used nowadays, makes use of a
>   Lyapunov function $V(x)$ which has an analogy to the potential
>   function of classical dynamics. It is introduced as follows for a
>   system  $\dot{x} = f(x)$ having a point of equilibrium at x=0.
>   Consider a function $V(x)$ : $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 
>   such that:
>
> - $V(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$
> - $V(x)>0$ if and only if $x \ne 0$
> - $\dot{V}(x) = \frac{d}{dt}V(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial       V}{\partial x_i}f_i(x) \le 0$ for all values of $x$ (negative
>     semidefinite). Note: for asymptotic stability,  $\dot{V}(x)<0$  for $x
>   > \ne 0$ is required (negative definite).

In your example, a candidate for a Lyapunov function is $V(x,y) = x^2 +y^2$.

Note: the method in the article, as it stands, will give you the behavior for $a=0$ and $a<0$. Here is the additional case:

> Suppose $X$ is a $C^{1}$ vector field on an open set $\Omega \subset
> > \mathbb {R}^n$, $0 \in \Omega$ is a critical point of $X$, and $V :
> > \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ is a continuous function such that
>
> - $V (0) = 0$
> - there exists $\Omega_{-} \subset \Omega$ such that $\Omega_{-} \cap B_{\delta}(0)= \emptyset$ for any $\delta >0$, $V (x) < 0 \ \forall
>   > x\in \Omega_{-}$, $V (x) = 0 \ \forall x\in \partial \Omega_{-} \cap
>   > B_{\epsilon} (0)$ for some $\epsilon >0$;
> - $V$ is strictly decreasing on the part of orbits that stay in $\Omega$.
>
> Then $0$ is unstable.

In the case of $a>0$, let $V(x,y) = -x^2 -y^2$ and use the theorem above.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Can you try hard to find the result for the case $a > 0$? I still wonder why the Local Center Manifold doesn't work in this case:p

Comment: There you go! I have added the additional case for instability @user177196

Comment: @GaussTheBauss Well, your method is not so offbeat. Because even when we reduced system to the center manifold, we have to prove the stability of equilibrium and (guess what) Lyapunov function is needed exactly in the same way :)

Comment: @GaussTheBauss Also, proving instability can be done with Chetaev's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chetaev_instability_theorem).

Comment: Aha! I did not know the name of the theorem. It is however exactly what I added at the end of my answer. Thanks for your input! @Evgeny

Comment: @GaussTheBauss: Thanks a lot for your help. I have a follow up question: which invariant manifold exists at the origin?

Comment: @GaussTheBauss: I have a question: how can $V(x,y) = -x^2-y^2$ satisf the 2nd condition? I meant, if $x$ belongs to the intersection for some $\epsilon > 0$, then $V(x) < 0$. Unless the intersection is only an origin, which seems to be the case here. Am I correct?